# Paypal Express checkout + php cURL Execute payment not show payment notification on sandbox

Tags: javascript, php, curl, paypal-sandbox, express-checkout

i'm testing paypal integration, in a php demo test on my apache server with a vhost -> test.it/paypal.
I use Express Checkout + Server-side REST (cURL).
My js Add the PayPal button is:

```js
<script>

      var CREATE_PAYMENT_URL  = 'http://test.it/paypal/create-payment.php';
      var EXECUTE_PAYMENT_URL = 'http://test.it/paypal/execute-payment.php';

      paypal.Button.render({

          env: 'sandbox', // Or 'production',

          commit: true, // Show a 'Pay Now' button

          locale: 'it_IT',

          style: {
              size: 'small',
              color: 'blue',
              shape: 'pill',
              label: 'checkout'
          },

          commit: true, // Show a 'Pay Now' button

          payment: function() {

              // Make a call to the merchant server to set up the payment

              return paypal.request.post(CREATE_PAYMENT_URL).then(function(res) {
                  //return res.payToken;
                  console.log(res);
                  return res.paymentID;
              });
          },

        // Wait for the payment to be authorized by the customer

        onAuthorize: function(data) {
          //alert(data.payerID);
            return paypal.request.post(EXECUTE_PAYMENT_URL, {
                paymentID: data.paymentID,
                payerID:   data.payerID
            }).then(function(res) {
              /* Go to a success page */
                console.log('SUCCESS!!!!!!!!!');
                console.log(res);
                // The payment is complete!
                // You can now show a confirmation message to the customer
                alert('pagamento completato');
            }).catch(function (err) {
              /* Go to an error page  */
              console.log('ERROR!!!!!!!!!');
              console.log(data);
              console.log(err);
          });
        }

      }, '#paypal-button');
    </script>
```

**The create-payment.php is as follows:**

```html
<?php
session_start();
include 'config.php';

// autenticazione per ottenere user token
$url_wbs="https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token";


$ch = curl_init();
$clientId = "Aeet9T-pG4XQU-GnDL2uSrkJQ4_qaxgAu9XtVTP6qeuXDGBOnHf2TiVF2Qv5OurFmSo9dPkwVk-x0J3x";
$secret = "EGQguUgHcN4TLjAEAXb4Jo8qoTQCvC3o_54FL2r2wQUtjbGoRoWeRlDyNNhU3HO8lpdexzNsW-ePb2qe";
// id web experience profile
$experience_profile_id="XP-V52K-SKNH-FK7Y-HLYQ";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_wbs);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $clientId.":".$secret);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=client_credentials");

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
if(empty($result))die("Error: No response.");
else
{
    $obj=json_decode( $result );

   //var_dump($obj->access_token);
   $_SESSION['token']=$obj->access_token;

   // imposto il web profile ottenendone l'id
   $header_rest_call[]='Authorization: Bearer '.$obj->access_token;


   $json_body='{
  "intent": "sale",
  "experience_profile_id":"'.$experience_profile_id.'",
  "redirect_urls":
  {
    "return_url": "http://test.it/paypal/checkout.php",
    "cancel_url": "http://test.it/paypal/pagamento-cancellato.php"
  },
  "payer":
  {
    "payment_method": "paypal"
  },
  "transactions": [
  {
    "amount":
    {
      "total": "4.00",
      "currency": "EUR",
      "details":
      {
        "subtotal": "2.00",
        "shipping": "1.00",
        "tax": "2.00",
        "shipping_discount": "-1.00"
      }
    },
    "item_list":
    {
      "items": [
      {
        "quantity": "1",
        "name": "item 1",
        "price": "1",
        "currency": "EUR",
        "description": "item 1 description",
        "tax": "1"
      },
      {
        "quantity": "1",
        "name": "item 2",
        "price": "1",
        "currency": "EUR",
        "description": "item 2 description",
        "tax": "1"
      }]
    },
    "description": "The payment transaction description.",
    "invoice_number": "merchant invoice",
    "custom": "merchant custom data"
  }]
}';

   $obj_payment=get_obj_json($payment_creation_url,$header_rest_call,$json_body,'POST');

   //var_dump($obj_payment->id);
   $response=array(
     'paymentID'=>$obj_payment->id
   );

   echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

**The execute-payment.php is as follows:**

```html
<?php
session_start();
include 'config.php';


   // imposto il web profile ottenendone l'id
   $header_rest_call[]='Authorization: Bearer '.$_SESSION['token'];

  // indirizzo wbs per pagamento
  $url_payment="https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/".$_POST['paymentID']."/execute/";

  $json_body='{
    "payer_id": "'.$_POST['payerID'].'";
  }';

  $obj_payment=get_obj_json($url_payment,$header_rest_call,$json_body,'POST');

  echo json_encode($obj_payment);


?>
```

When I click on the paypal button the paypal login form correctly appears with the purchase data, I enter the credentials and finally i click on the "pay now"
 button. It seems that the payment was successful.. but in the sandbox account -> activity -> There is no trace of transitions/payments..?

Comment: Are those your real `clientId` and `secret`? I wouldn't publish those ...

Comment: Taken in a hurry .. now I deleted the app. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the malformed json of the payment/execute request.

```
$json_body='{
"payer_id": "'.$_POST['payerID'].'";
```

}';

There was a semicolon I mistakenly entered after  -> $_POST['payerID'].'"

Now it works!

Comment: i want to integrate the same on my website can you tell me what is there in config.php and i am receiving the error Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_obj_json()