# Paypal Express Checkout Server-side REST execute payment (php cURL)

Tags: php, rest, curl, paypal

I made a Express Checkout with Server-side REST (php cURL).
The create-payment is working and i receive the access_token and also the payment ID.

Now i try to make the execute-payment and cant receive the $_SESSION['token'], $_POST['payerID'] and $_POST['paymentID'] in my execute-payment.php.

Similar like this Question 
[Paypal Express checkout + php cURL Execute payment not show payment notification on sandbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44021693/paypal-express-checkout-php-curl-execute-payment-not-show-payment-notification/46977563#46977563)

I did various Test-Settings and nothing is working?
In the Browser-Developer-Console i see the payerID and paymentID under Form Data. How can i access these in my execute-payment.php ?

Comment: and its similar to this post on the same topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45897900/php-paypal-server-side-rest-integration-failure

Comment: is it just possible with the PayPal-PHP-SDK?